# Blog title on top of featured image? Avada Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I use wordpress to develop websites and I'm using the Avada Simple Theme. However I cannot seem to get the post title on top of the featured image. Has figured a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Some custom themes might not display post title on top of the featured image so you might have to edit the archive.php,index.php etc pages to add wp_title

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Yes I understand that, the issue is that I dont know how to do that.